# Property 'icon' does not exist on type 'HTMLAttributes' - why can't I log out this part of object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ts-jest

Running a Jest test in Typescript

test.tsx

```
it('should render Facebook Icon in Footer', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<Footer />);
        const renderedProps = wrapper.find('FontAwesomeIcon').at(0).props();
        console.log('rendered props: ', renderedProps); // LOGS OUT
        console.log('rendered props icon: ', renderedProps.icon); // ERRORS
    });
```

logged out rendered props looks like this:

```
rendered props:  { 
   onClick: [Function: onClick],
   icon: [Function], // ICON IS VERY CLEARLY THERE.
   size: 'xs'
}
```

Instead I get this error:

```
Property 'icon' does not exist on type 'HTMLAttributes'.
```

I'm very new to Typescript. Wondering if I'm supposed to overwrite the type somehow?

I just want to run checks on the props that are being passed to my mock `<FontAwesomeIcon />`

Help?

Comment: @PositiveGuy i found a couple of ways around it... first one was adding: `//@ts-ignore` above anything that was causing errors. Not great but gets you through. Next one was within React <Component>s and declaring the entire shape of the object in an `interface`. I still think Typescript is annoying AF, but i'm trying! I'm really trying.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but it'll hopefully get you closer

```
import { AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes } from 'react';

declare module 'react' {
    interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
        icon?: Function;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a miliar problem by creating an interface for the props to be tested extending HTMLAttributes and adding my own properties; and then asserting the type returned from *.props().*

In your case, I believe something like this could work (adapt the functions types to your needs):

```
interface IProps extends HTMLAttributes {
   onClick: (event: MouseEvent) => void;
   icon: () => string; // Or whatever you return as an icon
   size: string;
}
```

Then use type assertion:

```
it('should render Facebook Icon in Footer', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Footer />);
  const renderedProps = wrapper.find('FontAwesomeIcon').at(0).props() as IProps;
  expect(renderedProps.size).toBe('xs'); // passed OK
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: This is **how** we solve the problem, but what's the **reason**?